# Sorting of data frame per date and string value

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I am downloading data from Bloomberg and then update it in R. The dataframe looks as follows.

```
 ticker       date PX_LAST PE_RATIO
1 SMI Index 2014-09-30 8835.14  20.3692
2 SMI Index 2014-10-31 8837.78  20.3753
3 DAX Index 2014-09-30 9474.30  16.6487
4 DAX Index 2014-10-31 9326.87  16.3896
5 SMI Index 2014-11-28 9150.46  21.0962
6 SMI Index 2014-12-31 8983.37  20.6990
7 DAX Index 2014-11-28 9980.85  17.5388
8 DAX Index 2014-12-31 9805.55  16.8639
```

Now I would like to have this dataframe sorted according to ticker (not in alphabetical order, but in the order of the ticker) and then the date so that the end result would be:

```
 ticker       date PX_LAST PE_RATIO
1 SMI Index 2014-09-30 8835.14  20.3692
2 SMI Index 2014-10-31 8837.78  20.3753
3 SMI Index 2014-11-28 9150.46  21.0962
4 SMI Index 2014-12-31 8983.37  20.6990
5 DAX Index 2014-09-30 9474.30  16.6487
6 DAX Index 2014-10-31 9326.87  16.3896
7 DAX Index 2014-11-28 9980.85  17.5388
8 DAX Index 2014-12-31 9805.55  16.8639
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a function `chgroup()` in the `data.table` package that does exactly what you're looking for. It groups values from the vector together while preserving the initial order. It is only available for character vectors (`ch` for character).

```
require(data.table)
DF[chgroup(DF$ticker), ]
#     ticker       date PX_LAST PE_RATIO
# 1 SMIIndex 2014-09-30 8835.14  20.3692
# 2 SMIIndex 2014-10-31 8837.78  20.3753
# 5 SMIIndex 2014-11-28 9150.46  21.0962
# 6 SMIIndex 2014-12-31 8983.37  20.6990
# 3 DAXIndex 2014-09-30 9474.30  16.6487
# 4 DAXIndex 2014-10-31 9326.87  16.3896
# 7 DAXIndex 2014-11-28 9980.85  17.5388
# 8 DAXIndex 2014-12-31 9805.55  16.8639
```

If your `ticker` column is `factor`, then convert it first to `character` type.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `order`

```
 df$ticker <- factor(df$ticker, levels=unique(df$ticker))
 df1 <- df[with(df, order(ticker, date)),]
 row.names(df1) <- NULL
 df1
 #     ticker       date PX_LAST PE_RATIO
 #1 SMI Index 2014-09-30 8835.14  20.3692
 #2 SMI Index 2014-10-31 8837.78  20.3753
 #3 SMI Index 2014-11-28 9150.46  21.0962
 #4 SMI Index 2014-12-31 8983.37  20.6990
 #5 DAX Index 2014-09-30 9474.30  16.6487
 #6 DAX Index 2014-10-31 9326.87  16.3896
 #7 DAX Index 2014-11-28 9980.85  17.5388
 #8 DAX Index 2014-12-31 9805.55  16.8639
```